# How can I pass ARM template parameters through the API instead of a parameter file?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-resource-manager

I'm attempting to automate the creation of some resources in Azure using Azure Resource Manager .NET libraries. I am able to create the Resource Group and have placed my ARM template in an accessible location on blob storage; however, I would like to be able to pass in the parameters to the request in code instead of staging a JSON file somewhere in storage.

It seems like this should be possible. For example, on the `Deployment.Properties` object, it has both `Parameters` and `ParametersLink`, but I cannot find any documentation on its usage and the following is throwing an exception saying that no value was specified for the parameters in the template:

```
deployment.Properties = new DeploymentProperties
{
    Mode = DeploymentMode.Incremental,
    TemplateLink = new TemplateLink("link-to-my-template-json-in-storage"),
    Parameters = new
    {
        diskStorageAccountName = "value",
        imageVhdPath = "value",
        virtualNetworkName = "value",
        virtualNetworkSubnetName = "value",
        vmName = value,
        vmAdminUserName = "value",
        vmAdminPassword = "value"
    }
};
```

This yields the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Deployment template validation failed: 'The value for the template parameter 'diskStorageAccountName' at line '5' and column '32' is not provided. Please see http://aka.ms/arm-deploy/#parameter-file for usage details.'.

Am I doing something wrong? `DeploymentProperties.Parameters` is just an `Object` so I had assumed that it would be serialized and passed on correctly -- is this assumption incorrect?

Edit: The [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.management.resources.models.deploymentproperties.parameters.aspx) is not very helpful either.

Edit 2: I wonder if this is a bug in the autogenerated code. See line 700 here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/src/ResourceManagement/Resource/ResourceManagement/Generated/DeploymentOperations.cs

Looks like it is trying to `JObject.Parse`

Edit 3: Opened an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/1749).

Comment: What is the specific nuget package and version you're using? I will try to reproduce and resolve your issue.

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resources 3.3.1-preview

Comment: @juvchan: Any updates please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the **`Deployment Properties Parameters`**, you should use the **`JObject`** type from the **`Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`** namespace.

E.g.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
// paramJsonString is a string type object
Parameters = JObject.Parse(paramJsonString);
```

Note: The **`Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resources`** nuget package will be deprecated.

> Strongly recommend to use **`Microsoft.Azure.ResourceManager
>   1.0.0-preview`** [Microsoft.Azure.ResourceManager](http://Microsoft.Azure.ResourceManager%201.0.0-preview) for your development related to Azure Resource Manager.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [source code testing](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/21db6e5490e66af39a9c6dbf0ad10650d9ca037b/src/ResourceManagement/ApiManagement/ApiManagement.Tests/SessionRecords/ResourceGroups.Tests.LiveDeploymentTests/CreateDeploymentAndValidateProperties.json), it has something of an odd layout...

> @"{ 'siteName': {'value': 'mctest0101'},'hostingPlanName': {'value': 'mctest0101'},'siteMode': {'value': 'Limited'},'computeMode': {'value': 'Shared'},'siteLocation': {'value': 'North Europe'},'sku': {'value': 'Free'},'workerSize': {'value': '0'}}",

There is also an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/1707) raised with similar problems

I've not currently got time to test this! so if it doesn't work let me know and I'll delete this answer.

Comment: I've tried serializing the object as well; it ends up...setting `parameters` in the request to a JSON string, also fails.